# Router-Outlet Navigation With Constant Sidebar and NavBar on Angular

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I’m a bit confused on what to do on how to place my router-outlet. I have tried researching for similar cases but to no avail. 
Here is the scenario 
I have a dashboard component which loads after a login is successful. The dashboard contains a sidebar, footer and navigation component declared on the html. Now, when I click on a user link to show me the list of users, it loads the user component but the sidebar, footer and navigation disappears and I am left with only the user component. I just want a situation when I click on a link in the sidebar, it just changes the content without removing the sidebar, footer and nav……
PS: the user component has its own module, then I imported this into the appModule as usual.

Here is what I have so far.

app.component.html

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

dashboard.component.html

```
<side-bar></side-bar>
<topnav-bar></topnav-bar>
<content></content>
<footer></footer>
```

sidebar.component.html

```
 <li>
            <a id="formsli" (click)="anchorClicked($event)"
              ><i class="fa fa-user"></i> User<span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span
            ></a>
            <ul class="nav child_menu">          
              <li><a [routerLink]="['/user/list']">User List</a></li>
              <li><a [routerLink]="['/user/new']">New User</a></li>
            </ul>
 </li>
```

usersRouteFile

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'user/list', component: UsersComponent },
    { path: 'user/new', component: UserComponent },
];
```

appModule

```
export const AppRoutes2: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LoginComponent},
  { path: 'content', component: ContentComponent },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
];

imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      RouterModule.forRoot(AppRoutes2, {useHash: false}),
      HttpClientModule,
      UsersModule,
   ],
```

If i click on the user list link, the sidebar, nav and footer disappears. I want it to remain and just change the content area.

Please, what am i doing wrong or not doing right??

Comment: Well Router Outlet replaces the components with whatever is loaded. So if navbar and sidebar aren’t part of the user component then they won’t be loaded. What you could do is load them all in the app component, either in a separate shared component or individually or one by one and use an ngif directive to show or hide the common components only if a user is logged in outside of the router outlet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**App.component.html**

```html
     //use the ngIf directive to either create or destroy the div with       static content (this is determined from the app.component.ta
      <div class='user-nav' *ngIf="isLoggedIn">
          <side-bar></side-bar>
          <top-navbar></top-navbar>
       </div>
     //anything that is routed will show up here
       <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    //if you want the footer to only be available after logging in add it here too
       <footer></footer>
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I kinda understand your logic here. But in a situation where the login page has its own component and there is no relationship between the app and login component. How then is the best way to update the property “isLoggedIn” in app component ts file before rendering its html??

Comment: well depends on your strategy for logging a user in, although I'm confused on how there is no relationship between the two, since the app component is the bootstapped component. If you are using localstorage to store session state you could look it up from there but presumably you have some sort of service that logs a user in, that app component can access.

Comment: Yeah, plan to use local storage to store the token of a user once login is successful so that i can easily get user data if i need...Maybe i will create a function to simply track loggedInUser .....Looks promising that way.

Comment: well you can also access localstorage from the app component and if it is a valid token then you can say the user is loggedIn, my presence usually is to have a topnav  that is always visible throughout the app that checks if a user is loggedIn when the site is launched. Using an observable I can keep track of the loggedin status without having to go back to my localstorage.

Comment: Thanks, i will also take that into consideration. Thanks again for the idea.